# Как проверить в цикле while возврат символа, не входящего в строку?

Tags: python

Нужна функция, которая проверяет, содержит ли строка указанную букву. Результаты проверки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я стал здесь:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
если открыть 3 проверку - не работает 1, и не уверен про 2 проверку

Comment: Все тексты должны быть текстами, а не скриншотами

Comment: И обязательно ли использовать while? Просто `return char in text` почему-то нельзя?

Comment: к сожалению код, заключенный в ``` ``` не всегда принимает

Comment: @cubinez85 всегда принимает. Если у вас "не принимает", значит вы что-то не так делаете.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
text = 'Hello, world'
letter = 'e'
```

вариант 1:

```
letter in text
```

вариант 2:

```
text.find(letter) != -1
```

вариант 3:

```
any(letter == l for l in text)


not all(letter != l for l in text)
```

вариант 4:

```
res = False

for l in text:
    if l == letter:
        res = True
        break
```

вариант 5:

```
len(set(letter) & set(text)) != 0
```

вариант 6:

```
{l: True for l in text}.get(letter, False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Немного изменив код, можно добиться прохождения тестов

```
def f(text, ch):
    index = 0
    while index < len(text):
        if ch == text[index]:
            return True
        index += 1
    return False

print(f('Hello', 'H'))          # => True
print(f('Hello', 'h'))          # => False
print(f('Awesomeness', 'm'))    # => True
print(f('Awesomeness', 'd'))    # => False
```

Но как сказал @andreymal, проще

```
def f(text, ch):
    return ch in text
```

Answer (score 0):

3 проверку надо вынести за пределы цикла:

````
    index = 0
    if char != text[index]:
        return char in text
    while index <= len(text):
        if char == text[index]:
            return True
        if char == text[index].lower():
            return False
        # if char == :
        #     return False
        index += 1
    return
text = 'Hello'
print(f(text, char='H'))```
````